# How to determine if a set of square matrices that all have inverses is in a vector space over R

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am trying to understand how vector spaces relate to square matrices. I think my issue is that I'm being asked if a set of all square matrices $2\times 2$ with real numbers is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. I guess I don't understand how a vector space can be over real numbers.

I guess I understand that a subspace of $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ where values in the matrices are real numbers would be any matrix with one set of diagonal zeroes, but I am not sure how that compares with asking if all $2\times2$ matrices in the set can be a vector space.

Comment: Can you spell out the '*I guess I understand*' part?

Comment: I tried to do that now, and also I forgot to mention that the set is invertible 2x2 matrices in the space of real numbers.

Comment: @Veneratu Saying that a vector space is "over the real numbers" means that the field elements (i.e. scalars) that can multiply the vectors are real numbers (as opposed to, for instance, complex numbers or number from a finite field).

Comment: Thanks Ben. Out of curiosity, if the invertible matrices were then all in R^2x2, would that mean they wouldn't be a subspace of R any longer because scalars could be complex?

Comment: The problem with the set of invertible matrices is that it doesn't contain a zero